# What is a proper principal minor?

Tags: linear-algebra

I recently came across the term proper principal minor but couldn't find its definition by googling.

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $I\subseteq\{1,\cdots,m\}$ with $k$ elements and $J\subseteq \{,\cdots,n\}$ with $k$ elements let $A_{IJ}=(a_{ij})$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ with $i\in I$ and $j\in J$. If $I=J$ then det $A_{IJ}$ is called a principal minor.

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) goes on to define leading principal minor and basic minor however there is no mention of proper minor. Could someone tell me what it is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mathematics, "proper" is a qualifier on a defined term that excludes trivial cases. Examples:

- $X$ is a proper subset of $Y$. This means that $X$ is a subset of $Y$ but $X \neq Y$. The trivial case here is that a set is always a subset of itself.
- $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. This means that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ but $H \neq G$. The trivial case here is that a group is always a subgroup of itself.
- $M$ is a proper minor of $A$. This means that $M$ is a minor of $A$ but $M \neq \det A$. The trivial case here is that the determinant of a matrix is always a minor of that matrix.

This use of the word "proper" is a common scheme throughout math.